# CW-complex structure of $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ with $S^1 \times \{1\}$ collapsed to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

> Consider the $2$-torus $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ and consider the space $X = T^2/(S^1 \times \{1\})$, $T^2$ with $S^1 \times \{1\}$ collapsed to a point. What CW-complex structure does $X$ have and how would we compute its fundamental group?

I am not sure how to think about this. It seems to me that $X$ would just be homeomorphic to a circle, but I am not sure.

Comment: $H_2$ of a circle is 0, but $H_2(X)$ isn't. So they certainly are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a comment, but one cannot post images as comments.

Here is an image of what the space looks like. This should help you in finding a suitable CW-structure. Also, this topological space is a called a [pinched torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinched_torus).

[image]

Also, the space is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ as illustrated in [Hatcher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwja9Z6XsqboAhVcUhUIHfc5DwEQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpi.math.cornell.edu%2F~hatcher%2FAT%2FAT.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2uCLe8pwJfnFPY3JGfePWO) Example 0.8. WIth this one can compute the fundamental group of the space to be $\mathbb{Z} (= \{0\} \ast \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. A suitable CW-complex structure would then be one $0$-cell (the "pinching point"), one $1$-cell attached to that pinching point and one $2$-cell attached on the $1$-cell? And how would we prove that this is just $S^2 \lor S^1$? Is having the same CW structure sufficient to conclude this?

Comment: Important: Its not "just" $S^2 \vee S^1$, it homotopy equivalent, not homeomorphic and not equal.

Comment: Yes, I meant homotopy equivalent. Thank you!

Comment: Proving that the two are homotopy equivlancet would require one to construct an explicit homotopy. Having the same CW structure would suffice, but the two don't have the same since then they would be homeomorphic, which they are not.